# How to call registered javascript on selected plugin pages only in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

What I want is to add my custom javascript to my plugin's home page only.

Here is what I did:

**1. First registered my script,**

```
function register_my_plugin_script() {
        /* Register our script. */
        wp_register_script( 'my-plugin-script', plugins_url('/script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
    }
add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_my_plugin_script' );
```

**2. Then made a call to it,**

```
function call_my_script(){
  wp_enqueue_script( 'my-plugin-script' );
}
```

**3. Then tried to call it only in my home page like this:**

```
function my_home_page(){
   add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'call_my_script');
}
```

**But it did not add the script.**

Further code of adding menu page :

```
function my_menu_pages(){
  add_menu_page('some title', 'some menu', 'manage_options', 'my-plugin-homepage', 'my_home_page');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_menu_pages');
```

**Note:**
if I include my script directly in `my_home_page` function without registering or calling like this, then it works.

```
function my_home_page(){
   wp_enqueue_script( 'my-plugin-script', plugins_url('/script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
}
```

**What is the best way to do this?**

Answer (score 1):

There is a hook for your plugin's pages in the admin area - but it can be difficult to work out exactly what it is called.

Try this first:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_plugin_enqueue_scripts' );
function my_plugin_enqueue_scripts($hook) 
{
    echo "<!-- Hook = {$hook} -->" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

... then visit your plugin's page in the admin area and view the HTML source to find the output of that variable. Alternatively, set a breakpoint and view it in your debugger.

Once you've found the hook name, you can do the following in your plugin code:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_plugin_enqueue_scripts' );
function my_plugin_enqueue_scripts($hook) 
{
    if ($hook == 'my_plugin_page_hook-location')
    {
        wp_register_script(...);
        wp_enqueue_script(...);

        wp_register_style(...);
        wp_enqueue_style(...);      
    }
}
```

Comment: It did included the script but it does not perform action according to script. But when i include it as i have it in the bottom of my question then it works. Any idea ?

Comment: Does the script appear in the HTML output for the page? Has the same script name ('my-plugin-script' in your example) already been registered elsewhere?

Comment: Yes it does appears when  view its page source, and no script with this name exists elsewhere.